# Making ios to wait job finish before enter in background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background

How to tell ios to wait for some job finish before going to background mode? 
I tried ApplicationWillResignActive method on Appdelegate, and put there some loop which are printing dummy data, but nothing was happened, data is printing on background mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is - you can't. You can't block going to background. The best you can do is start a job for a specific limited time, but it's done in background. There's no way of blocking the app to resign active.

Comment: In that case how is possible to stop active video recording session before background mode? because on background mode AVFoundation framework throws an exception, but if you look at native ios camera application, system waits for recording finish, and then after goes to background.Is there any limited time? lets say a second to prevent app for going background ?

Comment: Have you tried to stop the video recording when the  `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` method is called?

Comment: yes, i tried both -applicationDidEnterBackground: and 
-applicationWillResignActive: , sometimes it works as i expected, but in many cases AVFramework throws an exception.

Comment: `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` should return within 5 seconds, otherwise it will crash.